# Efficiently link intersections to including sets

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I am trying to draw lines between intersections, like this: [example pic - the diagram on the left](http://www.gghh.name/dibtp/images/venn3_lattice.png).

The data for this diagram is represented as an array of arrays, containing objects, each object represents a set of intersections:

```js
const intersections = [
    [
        {sets: ['A'], id: 1, count: 100},
        {sets: ['B'], id: 2, count: 100},
        {sets: ['C'], id: 3, count: 100}
    ],
    [
        {sets: ['A', 'B'], id: 4, count: 75},
        {sets: ['A', 'C'], id: 5, count: 75},
        {sets: ['B', 'C'], id: 6, count: 75}
    ],
    [
        {sets: ['A', 'B', 'C'], id: 7, count: 50}
    ]
]
```

I need to add to each object an array of target objects (by id), so that later I will draw a line between the two. Like so:

```js
const intersections = [
        {sets: ['A'], id: 1, count: 100, target: [4,5]},
        {sets: ['B'], id: 2, count: 100, target: [4,6]},
        {sets: ['C'], id: 3, count: 100, target: [5,6]}
    ],
    [
        {sets: ['A', 'B'], id: 4, count: 75, target: [7]},
        {sets: ['A', 'C'], id: 5, count: 75, target: [7]},
        {sets: ['B', 'C'], id: 6, count: 75, target: [7]}
    ],
    [
        {sets: ['A', 'B', 'C'], id: 7, count: 50, target: []}
    ]
]
```

I came up with a solution that works, however I feel like there could be a more efficient way to solve this, without a loop within a loop within a loop within a loop :).

My solution involves iterating over each array of objects, and linking each object to the object and the next array. There is no need to link them to the next 'level' of objects.

My solution:

```js
function addTargets(intersections) {
    for (let i = 0; i < intersections.length - 1; i++) {

        intersections[i].forEach(intersection => {

            intersection.sets.forEach(set => {

                intersections[i + 1].forEach(intersection2 => {

                    intersection.target = intersection.target || [];

                    if (intersection2.sets.includes(set)) {

                        intersection.target.push(intersection2.id);

                    }
                })

            })

        });

    }
}
```

Note: Drawing the lines later is not the issue, **Just figuring out an efficient way to create the links between the objects.**

```js
const intersections = [
    [
        {sets: ['A'], id: 1, count: 100},
        {sets: ['B'], id: 2, count: 100},
        {sets: ['C'], id: 3, count: 100}
    ],
    [
        {sets: ['A', 'B'], id: 4, count: 75},
        {sets: ['A', 'C'], id: 5, count: 75},
        {sets: ['B', 'C'], id: 6, count: 75}
    ],
    [
        {sets: ['A', 'B', 'C'], id: 7, count: 50}
    ]
];

function addTargets(intersections) {
    for (let i = 0; i < intersections.length - 1; i++) {

        intersections[i].forEach(intersection => {

            intersection.sets.forEach(set => {

                intersections[i + 1].forEach(intersection2 => {

                    intersection.target = intersection.target || [];

                    if (intersection2.sets.includes(set)) {

                        intersection.target.push(intersection2.id);

                    }
                })

            })

        });

    }
}

addTargets(intersections);


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(intersections) + '</pre>')
console.log(intersections);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got a bug in there, you must only link two intersections where *all* sets of the first appear in the sets of the other, not *any* of them like in your code. Other than that, you can of course simplify the code a bit with functional programming but using nested iteration is indeed the easiest way:

```
function addTargets(intersections) {
    for (let i = 0; i < intersections.length - 1; i++) {
        linkAll(intersections[i], intersections[i+1]);
    }
}
function linkAll(higherLevel, lowerLevel) {
    for (const intersection of higherLevel)
        intersection.target = lowerLevel.filter(intersection2 =>
            intersection.sets.all(set =>
                intersection2.sets.includes(set)
            )
        }).map(intersection2 => intersection2.id);
    }
}
```

The five levels of iteration aren't that bad actually. We also could do with four if you had not already grouped the intersections in levels (by number of set entries), but that would in fact be less efficient as we'd have to search more objects.

If we wanted to optimise, we could build a `Map` from the `sets` of the `higherLevel` intersections to the objects so that we can quickly look them up, and then enter the `lowerLevel` intersections as targets in exactly those objects where they belong.

```
// for key(['A', 'B']) === key(['A', 'B'])
function key(set) {
    return set.join("|");
    // or use JSON.stringify
    // make sure that all sets have their entries sorted if that's not already the case
}

// all subsequences of arr that have 1 element less than arr
function* subsequences1(arr) {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
        yield arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i+1));
}

function linkAll(higherLevel, lowerLevel) {
    for (const intersection of higherLevel)
        intersection.target = [];
    const intersections = new Map(higherLevel.map(i=> [key(i.sets), i]));
    for (const intersection of lowerLevel)
        for (const higher of subsequences1(intersection.sets))
            intersections.get(key(higher)).target.push(intersection.id);
}
```

With that, you could even drop the grouping by level (and the loop in `addTargets`), it would work even when you put your whole set of intersections as both `higherLevel` and `lowerLevel` at once. You only would need to add the empty set as a possible target.

Comment: The links are correct, as you can see, the object with id `2`, which has only the set 'B', links only to `4` and `6` which also include 'B', and not to `5` which doesn't.

Comment: Also, I think you have 5 loops total there, I'm trying to reduce the number of loops :D No offense.

Comment: @Derpanel That's only by sheer luck. There is no difference in your simple example indeed, but there would be in more complex cases. Consider an intersection with sets `[A, D]`, should that link to the intersection with `[A, B, C]` or not?

Comment: @Derpanel Also you can see when running your code that it produces `target: [7, 7]` (because *both* `A` and `B` are in `[A, B, C]`), while it should only link each target only once.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, you are right, I will correct that.

Comment: @Derpanel Yes, I have the same 5 levels of loops in there as you, but I wanted to write correct code first before optimising it.